# Symfony2 Re-organization config files : parameters.dist.yml issue

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I've followed document to re organize files in app/config directory.
Now I have config/common (with config, parameters, parameters.dist, routing, security & services files), and files for each environment in specific directories : app/config/dev and app/config/prod.

But now, when I try to send "composer -n install" to update autoload, I have this error :

`[InvalidArgumentException]

  The dist file "app/config/parameters.yml.dist" does not exist.

   Check your dist-file config or create it.`

I know this is a configuration problem, Symfony search my dist file in app/config, how can I redirect it to app/config/common ?

I don't know where is the "dist-file config" written in error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found !
It is in composer.json:

under "extra", "incenteev-parameters", I've changed value of "file".